streamlitのconfig.tomlの設定値について
streamlitのconfig.tomlの設定について以下がお分かりになりましたらご教示いただけますでしょうか。
maxUploadSize と maxMessageSize のデフォルト値は200になっておりますが、設定できる最大値はそれぞれいくつになりますでしょうか。

プログラム（Streamlitのソースコード）で制限していないので、どちらも設定できる最大値はありません。ただし、性能面に影響が出て正常に動作しなくなる可能性があるため、デフォルト値から大きくかけ離れた値にすることはできません。実質的な最大値は、環境に依存します。システムの要件やサーバーの最大メモリーなどを確認し、妥当な値を設定したうえで、性能検証をして問題ないか判断するのがいいと思います。
